# Sobolev function with compact supprt

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For a Sobolev function $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, I assume that $u$ also has compact support, then I guess $$u\in W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$$
My try: let $u_\epsilon$ be the mollification of $u$.
Since $u$ has compact support say $K$, then $u_\epsilon$ is also compactly supportly within $K$.
We also know that $u_\epsilon\to u$ in $W_{loc}^{k,p}(\Omega)$
so $u_\epsilon\to u$ in $W^{k,p}(K)$.
And since both $u_\epsilon$ and $u$ vanish in $\Omega-K$,
so we can conclude $$u_\epsilon\to u\mbox{ in }W^{k,p}(\Omega)$$
i.e. $u\in W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$.
Can someone check whether my guess and attempt make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I think you are correct, but there is still one more thing you should pay attention to that is the $K$ you defined is depends on $\epsilon$.
So, I recommend you to fix a $\epsilon_0$ satisfying $0<\epsilon_0<\frac{1}{2}dist(\partial\Omega,suppu)$, then set $K$ as $\overline{B(suppu,\epsilon_0)}$ which is compact, and notice more that $suppu$ and $suppu_\epsilon$ is contained in $K$, then you can discuss the convergence in this $K$ which is independent of choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: thank you very much!